# How to use opencv flann::KMeansIndex to quantize a new data after training

Tags: opencv, indexing, hierarchy, k-means

I want to use Opencv cv::flann::KmeansIndex to build a hierarchical k-means tree to do clustering.
And after doing

```
typedef cv::flann::L2<float> Distance;
int featureNum =1000000;
int dim =2;
float *data = new float[featureNum*dim]; 
for(int i=0;i<1000000;++i)
{   
    data[i*2]=(float)(rand()%255);
    data[i*2+1]=(float)(rand()%255);
}

cvflann::Matrix<Distance::ElementType> features(data,featureNum,dim);
float *center = new float[10000*2];
flann::Matrix<float> centers(center,10000,2);
cvflann::KMeansIndexParams indexParams(10,1);
int n = cvflann::hierarchicalClustering<Distance>(features,centers,indexParams);
cout<<n<<endl;
```

the 2D points are clustered into 10^4 categories.

But what if a new datum came, and how can I know which category it belongs to?
I think cv::flann::KmeansIndex may help.

And after doing this:

```
KMeansIndex<Distance> kmeans(features, indexParam, d);
kmeans.buildIndex();
```

The index is built.

But

How to quantize a new data point using the KmeansIndex?